# Display pop up window on context menu item click Java fx

Tags: java, javafx

I am very new to Java and Java FX and I have been struggling a lot in creating a pop up window on context menu click. My requirement is

1. Tree view -- done
2. Display context menu with few options New, Open on each tree node -- done
3. Now when I click new in context menu, I need to display a pop up window that shows a text of and a button. On clicking the button, text entered in text box should be created as child in the tree. -- struggling on this

It's just like how we right click on netbeans and see new button. Someone please help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: look at `TextInputDialog`s: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: if you new to javafx, i would suggest to take also a look at the tutorial at code.makery.ch -> http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/

Comment: thank you so much. This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyPopUp extends Stage {
   public MyPopUp () {
    super();
    this.setTitle("Pop");
    this.setResizable(false);
    // The important part
    this.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    BorderPane borderPaneOptionPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPaneOptionPane.setCenter(new TextArea()); // For example

    Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
    closeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        this.hide();
    });

    borderPaneOptionPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));

    Scene s = new Scene(borderPaneOptionPane);
    this.setScene(s);
}}
```

then simply use .show method to set it visible.

Hope I could help you.

Greetings Kaito

Comment: thank you so much. All the resources helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of Kaitos MyPopUp, maybe a little help for beginners.

```
    MyPopUp popUp = new MyPopUp();

    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem("Call PopUp");
    newItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            popUp.show();
        }
    });
    contextMenu.getItems().addAll(newItem);
```

To add a contextmenu to a TableView you can do something like this:

```
    tableView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,  new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)  
                contextMenu.show(tableView, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()); 
        }
    });
```